# How to write php code with MySQL for utf-8 (to display Chinese), calculate days

Tags: php, mysql

I'm an outsider for the php with MySQL.

For my below code is testing : http://www.findoutbusiness.com/company/index.php?crno=1

How to write php code for the below questions:

- How to write a code in order can support utf-8 / Chinese? Because now the Chinese company is showing  "?????" only. The phpMyAdmin - database is can support Chinese. ONLY the index.php cannot support Chinese.
- How to write a code for calculating the days ?
- If the Active Status is "Dissolved", then calculate "Date of Dissolution - Date of Incorporation"
- If the Active Status is "Live", then calculate "today - Date of Incorporation"

I want to show the company is running how many: ? year ? months ? days.

Thank you very much for your help & support !

```html
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "abc";
$password = "abc1234";
$dbname = "company";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



// select data

$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM ComData WHERE com_no = '. $_GET['crno'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pageTitle = $row['com_eng_name'] . $row['com_chi_name'];

        $com_no = $row['com_no'];   
        $com_eng_name = $row['com_eng_name'];
        $com_chi_name = $row['com_chi_name'];  
        $com_type = $row['com_type']; 
        $date_of_incorp = $row['date_of_incorp']; 
        $active_status = $row['active_status']; 
        $date_of_dissolution = $row['date_of_dissolution'];   
  $remarks = $row['remarks'];
 

    }
} else {
    echo "No Results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="rights" content="www.findoutbusiness.com" />
  <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?> - Hong Kong Company Information</title>
</head>

<body >
<h2 >Hong Kong Company Information</h2>

<form action="http://www.findoutbusiness.com/company/index.php" id="cse-search-box">
    <input type="text" name="crno" size="10" />
    <input type="submit"  value="Company Code Search" />
</form>  
<br>



<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>CR No.:<br>公司編號:</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $com_no; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Company Name:<br>公司名稱:</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $com_eng_name; ?> <?php echo $com_chi_name; ?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Company Type:<br>公司類別:</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $com_type; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Date of Incorporation:<br>成立日期:<br></strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $date_of_incorp; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Active Status:<br>公司現況:</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $active_status; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Date of Dissolution:<br>已告解散日期:</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $date_of_dissolution; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Remarks:</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $remarks; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>
The company <?php echo $days; ?> days
<br>
<b>
<a href="index.php?crno=<?php echo ($_GET['crno'] - 1); ?>" >Previous Company</a> | 
<a href="index.php?crno=<?php echo ($_GET['crno'] + 1); ?>" >Next Company</a>
</b>

<br><br>

<form action="http://www.findoutbusiness.com/company/index.php" id="cse-search-box">
    <input type="text" name="crno" size="10" />
    <input type="submit"  value="Company Code Search" />
</form>  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so... basically we should write the code for you?

Comment: Please help me, I don't know how to write it .

Comment: You should tell us, what you already tried, not just asking to solve your problem, start with the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). This small article [UTF-8 for PHP and MySQL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8) may get you started with the UTF-8 problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Chinese, for your question, you can add the following codes after creating connection.

```
if(!$conn->set_charset("utf-8")){
   exit("Error loading character set utf8".$conn->error);}
```

Hoping this can help you.